# Change element position when mouse change

Tags: javascript

I have dots on screen and i want push these dots with mouse. Dots must not close to cursor with given radius.

I am not sure is these is right way to calculate new position this but i have below code.

```
Dot.prototype.listenonmouseMove = function () {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        //calculate distance between mouse and dot
        let distance = Math.sqrt(((e.clientY - this.y) ** 2) + ((this.x -e.clientX) ** 2));

        //if smaller than given radius
        if (distance < 100) {
            let angle = Math.atan2((e.clientY - this.y), (this.x - e.clientX)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            this.y = parseInt(this.y + ((200 - distance) * Math.sin(angle)));
            this.x = parseInt(this.x + ((200 - distance) * Math.cos(angle)));

            this.x = this.x < 0 ? 0 : this.x;
            this.y = this.y < 0 ? 0 : this.y;
            this.changePosition()
        }
    })
};
```

Above code is not working properly. Pleas check snippet. When mouse moving you can see dots jumps to random place

```js
let Dot = function () {
    this.create();
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth) + 1;
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 1;

    this.changePosition();
    this.listenonmouseMove()
};

Dot.prototype.create = function () {
    let dot = document.createElement('div');
    dot.className = 'dot';
    this.node = dot
};


Dot.prototype.changePosition = function () {
    if (this.requestAnimationId) return;

    let p = () => {
        if (parseInt(this.node.style.left) === this.x && parseInt(this.node.style.top)=== this.y) {
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationId);
            this.requestAnimationId = false

        } else {
            this.node.style.left = this.x + 'px';
            this.node.style.top = this.y + 'px';
            requestAnimationFrame(p)
        }
    };

    this.requestAnimationId = requestAnimationFrame(p)
};

Dot.prototype.listenonmouseMove = function () {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        //calculate distance between mouse and dot
        let distance = Math.sqrt(((e.clientY - this.y) ** 2) + ((this.x -e.clientX) ** 2));

        //if smaller than given radius
        if (distance < 50) {
            let angle = Math.atan2((e.clientY - this.y), (this.x - e.clientX)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            this.y = parseInt(this.y + ((50 - distance) * Math.sin(angle)));
            this.x = parseInt(this.x + ((50 - distance) * Math.cos(angle)));

            this.x = this.x < 0 ? 0 : this.x;
            this.y = this.y < 0 ? 0 : this.y;
            this.changePosition()
        }
    })
};




let content = document.getElementById('content');

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let dot = new Dot();
    content.appendChild(dot.node)
}
```

```css
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but `e.clientY` can be assign directly to `style.top` and `e.clientX` to `style.left`. What is exactly that you're calculating? If you want animation from point to mouse position, maybe better to use css transitions instead.

Comment: It looks like you are adding the mousemove event listener to the document, for every single dot. It would be better to only set the even listener once, instead of for each dot. This could be a cause of bugs and slower performance.

Comment: @jcubic Imagen there is circle around mouse cursor with given radius. Dots must not be inside this circle. I want move dots with this circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same effect with canvas.

Create an array of dots. On mouse move, check distance to mouse and move away from the mouse.

Loop with requestAnimationFrame and draw the dots.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let dots = [];
let w = 0;
let h = 0;
let mouseRadius = 50;
let dotRadius = 2.5;
let dotsToSpawn = 100;
function resize(){
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
}
function init(){
  for(let i=0;i<dotsToSpawn;i++){
    dots.push({
      x: Math.random()*w,
      y: Math.random()*h,
      r: dotRadius
    });
  }
}
function update(mx, my){
 dots = dots.map(({x,y,r}) => {
   //move x,y of dot away from mouse
   let dist = Math.sqrt(((mx-x)**2)+((my-y)**2));
   let angle = Math.atan2(my-y, mx-x);
   while(dist < mouseRadius){
     x -= Math.cos(angle);
     y -= Math.sin(angle);
     dist = Math.sqrt(((mx-x)**2)+((my-y)**2));
   }
   return {x,y,r}
 });
}
function draw(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
 ctx.beginPath();
 dots.forEach(({x,y,r}) => {
   ctx.moveTo(x+r, y);
   ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2);
 });
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
 ctx.fill();
}
function loop(){
 draw();
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
  update(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
resize();
init();
loop();
```

```css
canvas {
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"/>
```

You can do the same with html elements, instead of canvas:

```js
let dots = [];
let w = 0;
let h = 0;
let mouseRadius = 50;
let dotRadius = 2.5;
let dotsToSpawn = 100;
function resize(){
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
}
function init(){
  for(let i=0;i<dotsToSpawn;i++){
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    let x = Math.random()*w;
    let y = Math.random()*h;
    el.classList.add("dot");
    el.style.left = x+"px";
    el.style.top = y+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    dots.push({
      x,
      y,
      r: dotRadius,
      el
    });
  }
}
function update(mx, my){
 dots = dots.map(({x,y,r,el}) => {
   //move x,y of dot away from mouse
   let dist = Math.sqrt(((mx-x)**2)+((my-y)**2));
   let angle = Math.atan2(my-y, mx-x);
   while(dist < mouseRadius){
     x -= Math.cos(angle);
     y -= Math.sin(angle);
     dist = Math.sqrt(((mx-x)**2)+((my-y)**2));
   }
   el.style.left = x+"px";
   el.style.top = y+"px";
   return {x,y,r,el};
 });
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
  update(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});
resize();
init();
```

```css
.dot {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}
```